# Selecting an entire table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select all the rows from a specific table in SQL?

Comment: Obviously he's a new user and before it gets worse, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); AADHITHYAN.

Comment: To select all **rows** from a table you should just remove any `TOP N` in the sql query. To select all **columns**, you can name all of them in the query (and update the query when a column is added), or use `*`

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

This is how it works, the star will return all the records available in the specified table

**Recommendation:** Avoid using the star (`*`), use explicit column names instead:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table_name
```

Comment: It is recommended to avoid using `*`.. use explicit column names instead

Comment: the question was how to select all `columns` and rows

Comment: and the answer should be `SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table` :)

Comment: what if one more column is added to a table? the query will have to change too...but i get your point, i was just giving him what he wants

Comment: I get the point too :) That's why I used the `recommended` word :) you can add both cases in your answer..

Answer (score 2):

You should use following queries.

**For Example: Write the query as:**

```
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name, age, subject FROM student_details;
```

**Instead of using this:**

```
    SELECT * FROM student_details;
```

It will improve performance. Because the query is optimized.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the SQL `SELECT` Statatemnt

```
SELECT * FROM tablename;
```

Try this on a demo relation over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp).

---

If you are trying to insert data from an exiting table into another table you can again use the `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable
FROM initialtable;
```

you could also explicitly name the columns,

```
SELECT column1, column2
INTO newtable
FROM initialtable;
```

read more about it over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp).